# What are the possible implementations of LUT on silicon?

Tags: circuit-design, multiplexer, memory, hardware, chip-design

I'm looking for the possible ways to implement a LUT. The only way I know is to use Flip Flops to store the outputs and a MUX to select the output using the input as a select signal. Is there any other way to implement it?

Comment: Do you mean by *"on silicon"* that the contents of the LUT are defined at design time (a.k.a Read Only Memory)? Additionally to this, there could be alternatives for non-volatile (EEPROM/Flash) and volatile (RAM) silicon based implementations.

Comment: by "on slilcon" I meant on the transistor or on the logic gate level, how are they really implemented. do you know where I could find EEPROM/RAM's physical implementation ?

Comment: then edit your post to say that

Comment: This is really too broad of a question I think. A(n) LUT is just a block with some inputs and outputs. The optimal silicon implementation could be gates, ROM (maybe with data confined to one metal layer), RAM, EEPROM, EPROM, flash, fuses, multiplexer blocks etc. depending on the requirements and the technology available and other factors. A very sparse LUT would likely tend more towards logic implementation.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One alternative method to make a Look-Up Table is to use a parallel EEPROM chip.  The address bus are your inputs, and the data bus are your outputs.  The contents of the EEPROM are your logic output for the given "address" inputs.  Some supporting circuitry would be required to get the method to work, such as clocking.

Comment: How does the EEPROM look like on the transistor or the logic gate level ?

Comment: EEPROM (and EPROM and even RAM) generally is not made of whole logic gates. It looks like a great matrix of transistors, one transistor per memory bit and some control logic at the edges of the matrix.

Comment: @fraxinus thanks, this is actually what i wanted to know. a follow up question would be, do these types of memories (matrices of transistors) need flip flops to feed the stored values into a circuit ? or are they directly fed ?

Comment: Some buffering is inevitable, some address decoding is needed as well. One also needs to have some means of programming them (unless the whole thing is only mask-programmed ROM) so even more circuity.

Comment: @Hmdee To take this route, you'd need to generate a memory image of the EEPROM contents.  The "address" portion are your inputs, however you are designing them.  The "data" byte that resides at that address are the outputs that you want to appear for those given inputs.  And then of course, flash this image into the EEPROM chip.

Comment: I've seen this method of LUT be done before, such as data displays in avionics.  The bonus is that there is no software, so DO-178B need not apply, and I remember one customer for a black box that loudly specified NO SOFTWARE to make the data display.  We used this method and it worked great.